# Issue with aligning divs

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to create a simple CSS layot in my `ASP.NET` web page. However, I'm having some difficulties aligning `Divs` the way I want.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Please note that the right side where `.container` text and `.wrap` text should go all the way to right side. There should be no gap on the right side.

Here's my `html`:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="http://wiki.myexperiment.org/images/MyExperiment_logo_5016x960_trans.png" id="logo" /><div id="name">Welcome, John Smith</div>
        <div id="logout"><a href="logout.aspx"><img src="http://s3.postimg.org/kpgjd1wi7/logout.png"/></a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">Left Wrap</div>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id ="topWrap"> Top Wrap
        </div>
        <div id="leftWrap"> Left Wrap
        </div>
        <div id="rightWrap"> Right Wrap
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my `CSS`:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-image:     url('http://s27.postimg.org/48jitw07n/Background_3_Darker.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

 .header {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 76px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

#logo {
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
padding-top: 9px;
width: 300px; 
height: 50px;
}

#name {
float: right;
margin-right: 100px;
display: inline-block;

}

#logout {
float: right;
padding-top: 19px;
display: inline;
margin-right: 35px;
}

.container {
margin-top: 50px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.left {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 10%;
height: 400px;
background-color: #B9D7D9;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrap {
margin-left: 12%;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
}

#topWrap {
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
}

#leftWrap {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin-left: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}
#rightWrap {
float: right;
margin-right: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Unfortunately, the output is not coming out as I'm expecting it to be.

Here's the [output](http://jsfiddle.net/e60c3zt0/2/)

Any suggestions on how I can align the `divs` properly?

Comment: for starters, your closing div tags for leftWrap and rightWrap should read `</div>` instead of `<div`

Comment: Hello @Sam I updated my answer with more details, feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are something need to be fixed, mainly the unclosed `<div>`, and some mismatched id and class selectors between the HTML and CSS.

I can see you have made such efforts, so I wrote the foundation for what you need based on your CSS, perhaps it will help you to understand and get started from there.

[**UPDATED JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e60c3zt0/6/) AND [**FULL DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e60c3zt0/6/embedded/result/)

[image]

One thing I want to say, I added a #user around the #name and #logout, that makes it easier to do the floating.

And the [**clear fix technique**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear), where I use `class="cf"` in the code.

```
<div id="header" class="cf">
    <img id="logo" src="path/to/logo.png" />
    <div id="user">
        <div id="name">
            Welcome, John Smith
        </div>
        <div id="logout">
            <a href="#"><img src="path/to/logout.png" /></a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Leave your comments for any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It got me started in the right direction. However, I have one issue that I'm still struggling with. I would like to set `height: 100%;` in `#leftWrap` however, that `div` doesn't go down. If I do set the `height:100%;` in `#leftWrap, #rightWrap` it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: In order to set `height:100%` work you need to make sure the parent element has set a height, in your case the `#container` does not have it. You can try give it a value and see.

Comment: I've tried to set the parent to 100%, however, it actually shrinks. http://jsfiddle.net/e60c3zt0/7/

Comment: `#container` still doesn't get a actual height, then it will look all the way to `body` and `html` see this http://jsfiddle.net/e60c3zt0/9/, i've made them be to 100%. The page will get a scroll bar because you have a position fixed header. There is no good solution for that yet.

Comment: OK, here we go, without scroll bar http://jsfiddle.net/e60c3zt0/12/ It was be able to done with css `calc()`. it looks really good now. You can create a new post if you get other questions. I've completed this one. good day!

Answer (score 1):

Now that your divs are closed, here are the issues I see immediately:

- You are referencing `.left` in your CSS, but nothing in your HTML has `class="left"`.  You have `id="left"`, which means your CSS should be updated to `#left`.
- You cannot use `inline-block` and `float` on the same element.  They are two completely different display types as "float" implicitly sets `display: block`.  Try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/e60c3zt0/4/

```
    #leftWrap {
       float: left;
       width: 50%;
       height: 50%;
    }
    #rightWrap {
       float: right;
       width: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It brought me closer to what I'm trying to accomplish. However, my `.topWrap` is on top of `.header` now. http://jsfiddle.net/e60c3zt0/3/

Comment: That's because you are using fixed positioning.  You must figure out how tall it is and push your content down accordingly.  See how your #left element has a margin-top of 50px.  You need to push your .container down too...